# List file in folder to tabuled text

Tags: bash, csv

In a folder i have file1 and file2, 
can i generate a file csv (xls) with similar format [image]

i have tried this code but not work

```
for fullname in *.rar; do
if [[ "$fullname" != *X* ]]; then
    name="${fullname%.*}"
    echo $name Y check this http://foo.$fullname >> csv.txt
elif [[ "$fullname" == *Z* ]]; then
    echo $name Z check this http://foo.$fullname >> csv.txt
else
    echo $name X check this http://foo.$fullname >> csv.txt 
fi
done
```

this is the my output;

1. X check this http://foo.file1_X.rar
2. file1_Y Y check this http://foo.file1_Y.rar
3. file1_Z Y check this http://foo.file1_Z.rar

Why in line1 not show the name file1_X ?
Why in line3 not show after name file1_Z the character Z ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition is wrong - you are saying "If the file does not have an X in the name, then do this:" which includes both file_Y and file1_Z, so they are both processed by the first condition. You should put the Z condition first, since it is the most specific. Line 1 of your example output does not show the filename as expected because you only set `$name` when the Y condition is met. You should instead move the `$name` variable assignment outside the if:

```
for fullname in *.rar; do
name="${fullname%.*}"
if [[ "$fullname" == *Z* ]]; then 
    echo $name Z check this http://foo.$fullname >> csv.txt
elif [[ "$fullname" != *X* ]]; then
    echo $name Y check this http://foo.$fullname >> csv.txt
else
    echo $name X check this http://foo.$fullname >> csv.txt 
fi
    done
```

A switch statement might be better:

```
for fullname in *.rar; do
    name="${fullname%.*}"
    case $name in
        *Z*  ) match=Z;;
        *Y*  ) match=Y;;
        *    ) match=X;;
    esac
    echo "$name $match check this http://foo.$fullname" >> csv.txt
done
```